# Javascript validation on Floating values

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

How to do decimal validation using javascript?

There is a text box which should accept only 24.00 or 24 or any value less than 24.00.
The text box also must allow if 23.99 is entered.

I tried it this way:

```
if (document.forms[0].hours!= undefined) {
    var val = document.forms[0].hours.value;
    if (val .match(/^\d{0,6}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/)) {
        alert("Invalid" +'${payType}'+"  Hours. The hours entered can not have more than 2 decimal places or should be in the range of 0 to 24 ");
        submitted=false;           
        return false;
    }
}
```

The values can be: 1.00 or 12.25 or 1.25 or 23.99 or 24 but not above these values. Any number below 24.00 or 24.

Comment: use parseFloat() to compare floats?

Comment: why dont you use `(val < 24)`;

Comment: The text box can have values like 23.99 and 24 but not above 24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer doing it  with regex try this

```
^(0+)?(24(\.00?)?|(\.00?)?|\.[0-9]+|0?[0-9](\.[0-9]{0,2})?|(0+)?[0-2][0-3](\.[0-9][0-9]?)?)$
```

Tested on all the values below

```
   0.0
  4.00
  4.01
024.0
  5.8
  2.95
 10.5
 10.00
023.9
011
 09.89
 09
  8.67
 24
 24.00
 24.0
 23.99
  0.00
  0
   .5
   .55
  6
 24.01  // fail
 13.90
 78.23  // fail
  1.56
  0.06
 25.00  // fail
 23.99
 41.00  // fail
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oK7eW9/9)

---

The section below isn't related to the answer but rather to the comments below. @Anto these are just a few of online resources on regex. Have fun ;)

---

Free online books (google for these books)

- Mastering Regular Expressions, 3rdEdition
- Introducing Regular Expressions
- Regular Expression Pocket Reference, 2nd Edition
- Regular Expressions Cookbook

Good websites

- [http://www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)
- [http://www.rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)
- [http://regexlib.com](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx)
- http://overapi.com/regex/

Online regex tester

- http://regex101.com/

Comment: it does not allow this value 1.56, we can enter any value below 24

Comment: it accepts this value too 24.01 but anything below 24 should be okay

Comment: @hex494D49 `00.00` too pass, but must be `0.00` or just `0` I think. @Anto its allows `1.56`.

Comment: @Anto As you can see there's only one fail. I'm trying to fix it :)

Comment: @hex494D49, thanks for your response. please help me to fix and let me know once you complete :) thanks

Comment: @hex494D49 it does not accept any value which has one decimal like, 10.5 or 4.5, please would you help me on that ?

Comment: @hex494D49 thanks for the prompt reply, it worked, thanks a lot again

Comment: @hex494D49 i am sorry to disturb you, the above one should also accept .5 or .55 kind of values also. any thing between 0 to 24 with decimal or without decimal. would you please help

Comment: @Anto I see, ok, in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @hex494D49, you are very cool and help others when they are in need, and expert in Regex too... Please help me to learn this when you have some time. I am from India

Comment: @hex494D49 i am sorry to disturb you again, it is not accepting 09 also, but i thing is also valid one, please dont mistake

Comment: @hex494D49, i am sorry for this again, 011 (as its less than 24)
023.9 (as its less than 24)
024.0 (as its equal to 24) these are also valid but does not accept as per the above regex

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58405/discussion-between-anto-and-hex494d49).

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below regex,

```
^(?:24\.00|24|(?:[0][1-9]|[1][0-9]|2[0-3])\.[0-9][0-9])$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tQ8vM6/5)

OR

If you don't want `0` before the digit then you could try the below

```
^(?:24\.00|24|(?:[1-9]|[1][0-9]|2[0-3])\.[0-9][0-9])$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tQ8vM6/6)

Comment: it should also accept 1 to 24 or 1.00 to 23.99 but your regex is not accepting any value between 1 to 24 but 1.00 to 24.00

Answer (score 0):

you can reverse thinking

allow any number above 24.00 or 24

```
var reg = /^(24\.(0[1-9]|[1-9]\d?)|([3-9]\d|[^0]\d{2,9}|2[5-9])(\.\d{1,2})?)$/

     3.33     fail
    23.00     ...
    24        ...
    24.00     ...
     0.00     ...
     0        ...
    24.01     pass
    34.01     ...
    34        ...
   120.18     ...

if (document.forms[0].hours!= undefined) {
    var val = document.forms[0].hours.value;
    if (!reg.test(val)) {
        alert("Invalid" +'${payType}'+"  Hours. The hours entered can not have more than 2 decimal places or should be in the range of 0 to 24 ");
        submitted=false;           
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expression for this at all.
In fact it would be a lot simpler to just do this:

```
if (document.forms[0].hours!= undefined) {
    var val = parseFloat(document.forms[0].hours.value);

    // Get the number of decimals
    var a = val.toString().split(".");
    var decimals = a.length > 1 ? a[1].length : 0;

    if (isNaN(val) || val < 0 || val > 24 || decimals > 2) {
        alert("Invalid" +'${payType}'+"  Hours. The hours entered can not have more than 2 decimal places or should be in the range of 0 to 24 ");
        submitted=false;           
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fair enough, added `isNaN` to the if statement to protect from strings as well.

Comment: Haha ok, sure. Added parseFloat to protect against empty strings.
My point is: regexp for this is to overcomplicate things and will only result in messy code, especially if it's a complicated expression.
A logical approach in code is something all (most) developers can read and understand.
If you have more requirements, you can simply add it to the if statement.

Comment: It is true, but i did not even think the way you thought of. thanks for that. and if i enter space and execute i get `Unable to get value of the property 'length': object is null or undefined `